# how to pass/simulate keypress inside vdi from local machine

Tags: c#

I need to pass key press events form local machine to virtual desktop. Am able to pass single key press of all combinations like alphabet, numbers, function keys, symbols, etc... But not able to pass key combinations with modifiers like ALT+TAB, CTRL+C/V/A/P, Shift+TAB etc... Am using `InputSimulator` as reference and below code is sample for simulating Function Key F5.

```
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.F5);
```

Note: I have used `SendKeys`, but its not worth as above for my requirement.

Comment: `How to develop a service`..simple answer... **write some code**

Comment: You should  start with MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If this is going to be generally used, you need to be aware that windows allows multiple users to log on so tracking activity using a single set of variables is kind of broken.